# Getting CC-Tray to work

Tags: cruisecontrol.net

I am trying to get cc-tray to work instead of using the web dashboard. I'm not sure how I can get the correct url for the server that my cruisecontrol is running on and I can't find any useful documentations online. Can anyone help?

Thanks

Comment: The best way, for responsiveness, is to use the .NET remoting option and directly ping the build server though. Through the web dashboard cna lag a little, and your cctray then depends on the web server. Leaving you one less troubleshooting option should your projects go dead on the dashboard

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends a bit on the version you use. It is always a good idea to use the version of CCTray that you download from your running instance of the CCNet dashboard (on the dashboard, in the left column, you'll find a link 'Download CCTray').

Then it is mostly a matter of "Add Server". Older versions required a Remoting connection that requires some ports open in your connection to CCNet. Nowadays, you can connect over HTTP.

Answer (score 13):

I had the same trouble and was resolved setting this Url in the Add Server (http): http://yourserver/ccnet/server/local/ViewServerReport.aspx. It works fine with this.

Comment: This answer helped. The exact URL that worked for me did not include the `cctray` component (http://yourserver/server/local/ViewServerReport.aspx)

Comment: Thanks, worked a treat - the specific link we needed was under the "Servers" heading in the left hand navigation.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a version after 1.1 then you will want to point your CC tray client to the web dashboard site.

You should make sure you have the CCNET dashboard setup of a web server then you can do the following.

- File > Settings > Build Projects (click add)
- Add Server (click)
- Choose Via the CruiseControl dashboard
- Enter the address of your web dashboard site.  Perhaps something like "yourserver.com/ccnet".  You can find this via browsing to the web dashboard then copying the URL upto the folder level.
- Click OK, choose the projects to watch
- Profit!