# How to get CCTray

Tags: cruisecontrol.net

I have successfully installed CruiseControl.Net server on windows 7 32 bit platform by CruiseControl.Net 1.8.0.0. setup file. But here there is no CCTray . Please let me know how to get CCTray.

Comment: Link to donwload latest: http://www.cruisecontrolnet.org/

Comment: If you are interested in using CCTray to monitor Jenkins or Travis CI, you can also consider a new alternative - [CatLight build monitor](https://catlight.io) that has build investigations and nicer UI.

Answer (score 29):

Download it from official source (file is CruiseControl.NET-CCTray-1.8.0.0-Setup.exe):
http://build.nauck-it.de/download/CruiseControl.NET-package/1.8.0.0/

You can get it also from **your** CC.NET server.
[image]

Comment: For latest version:
https://sourceforge.net/projects/ccnet/files/CruiseControl.NET%20Releases/, click latest version, download `CruiseControl.NET-CCTray-(version)-Setup.exe`

Comment: the 'latest version" you are pointing to is 2014-05-26. There's no new version of CC.NET.

Comment: My point is that it's not a link to a specific version, so will remain current. E.g. it points to `1.8.5`, whereas your link is `1.8.0`.

Answer (score 6):

If you go to the Web dashboard there is normally a link to download the tray. 
Usually on the top right.

Comment: Hi Simon ,
I am following the below site to create a sample build automation 
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/70327/Automate-Builds-using-SVN-MSBuild-Cruise-Control

In this for Configuring CCTray at step 4 , i have added a server address as " http://localhost:222/CCNET ". This address based on IIS server on my local system. But after adding this IP address, i am getting below error

Failed to connect to server: Unable to connect to the remote server

Please let me know the solution for this problem.

Comment: You usually get options for how you are connecting to the server,  ie net remoting or http. Try out a few of the other options. The message you are getting means it cannot connect to the service. Maybe you have a firewall blocking the port - 222, or the service isn't running?

Comment: If you still cannot get it to work, maybe this post will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/631097/getting-cc-tray-to-work

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem on CC.Net 1.5.x - installed it without IIS, and
found no Web Dashboard (to begin with). I wanted to control the CCNet Server.

I'm not sure if for 1.8 the CCTray application can only be downloaded separately from SF:
http://en.sourceforge.jp/projects/sfnet_ccnet/releases/

In my case, 1.5.7256.1, the installer for CCTray is there, in:

```
Program Files(x86)/CruiseControl.Net/webdashboard/cctray
```

You can install it after main CC.NET installation.