# How to trigger a cruise control .net build manually?

Tags: web-deployment, cruisecontrol.net, msbuild-task

I am trying to install cruise control on a windows server 2012, but there are some issue with IIS so I can not access the dashboard website.

I have modified the ccnet.config, is there a way to trigger the build without using dashboard website, so I can verify whether my setting is correct. Please help, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CC.Net "Tray" can be used to pop off builds..without going through the website.

[How to get CCTray](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11690310/how-to-get-cctray)

however, cctray needs to talk to some kind of service........so you may be in a catch22.

Answer (score 1):

cctray can directly connect to the cruise service via remoting. It does not have to go via the dashboard.

Comment: Yeah, upon re-reading my answer, you're right.  :-(

But there is yet another way : ccnet.exe itself.
If you use the windows-service, you can use CCNet.exe to trigger builds.
ccnet.exe p=projectname
this will force the build