# How to trigger a cruise control .net full integration manually?

Tags: continuous-integration, cruisecontrol.net

We have configured our CruiseControl.NET server to build daily using the **scheduleTrigger** block. I have changed the projects to use a new build block and don't want to have to wait for 11 pm for the next build to kick off to test that they all work.

I would like to manually trigger a full integration i.e. build all projects, not one by one via CCTray (there are 100+ projects).

While there are several build trigger blocks available (see http://cruisecontrolnet.org/projects/ccnet/wiki/Trigger_Blocks), none of them offer an on demand build.

I have neither the time nor the appetite to develop a custom trigger (http://dhvik.blogspot.co.uk/2010/05/writing-custom-trigger-for.html).

I also don't have easy access to the build server as it is in a very controlled environment.

I have checked the similar question [How to trigger a cruise control .net build manually?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28456810/how-to-trigger-a-cruise-control-net-build-manually), but that suggests using CCTray.

Is there a straightforward way to trigger a full rebuild of all projects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Create a new project, say called 'TriggerAllProjects'. It doesn't need any tasks, but does need to get a new label for each build.
2. Update each project to have its current trigger/s and an additional project trigger, which points to 'TriggerAllProjects'. See [ProjectTrigger](http://cruisecontrolnet.org/projects/ccnet/wiki/Project_Trigger)
3. Manually force the 'TriggerAllProjects' project, each of the 100+ projects that are started will detect a change in the version number and trigger a build of themselves.